# Describe the electrons defined by the following quantum numbers?

Tags: quantum-chemistry

n=3, l=1, ml=2; and
n=4, l=2, ml=-1

I know that the first one is in the third energy shell and the second one is in the fourth energy shell because n=3 and n=4 respectively. I also know that when l=1 it should be in the p orbital and l=2 should be in the d orbital. The next part I am a bit confused about!
In the third energy shell, my textbook shows there is no ml=2. Am I missing something?
In the fourth energy shell, where ml=-1 in which of the three p orbitals should the electron be, that is the x, y, or z one?

Comment: the $m_l$ quantum number range from $\pm l$ in steps of $1$ so there seems to be a typo in the first question.